# Run/Click-on command in Explorer right-click menu from CMD

Tags: windows, windows-10

There are some items on Explorer contextmenu, how can I run the command assosiated to specific contextmenu item?

The app I'm using is AutoDesk Desktop Connector, and I'd like to know the commands for its different context menu actions.

Comment: What contex menu item specifically?

Comment: The item is by an app. How can i find the item in the registery and get the command?

Comment: What app? What action?

Comment: It's "Autodesk Desktop Connector" and there are some actions such as "Download".

Answer (score 1):

[ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) would show all. Or see [this question how to find manually in registry](https://superuser.com/questions/1331160/is-it-possible-to-easily-find-the-command-prompt-equivalent-of-a-context-menu-it?rq=1).

Or if the commands run long enough, you could also look for them in [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and check the process properties. [image: process properties]